# IsTouchingLayers() does not detect collision

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection

I'm making a tile-based player controller for a top-down game that first throws out a "move point" transform to see if its path is clear, then moves to it if the move point does not collide with anything. I would really like to do this with layers, because making a simple "walls" layer to place colliders on would make development really easy, but I can't make this code work.
(also I am extremely new to Unity, C#, and stack exchange, heads up)

The code is as follows (included in the update function):

```
// Collision detection
        if (transform.position != movePoint.transform.position)
        {
            if (movePoint.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().IsTouchingLayers((1 << 3)))
            {
                Debug.Log("Collision");
            }
            else
            {
                // Move player
                transform.position = movePoint.transform.position;
                Debug.Log("Move");
            }

            // Reset movePoint position
            movePoint.transform.position = transform.position;
        }
```

Even when I attempt to move directly into the wall, moving still works and I only get the "Move" debug message in the console. Can anybody help me understand why this doesn't work?

Comment: Have you considered dispensing with the second transform entirely and instead using [Physics2D.OverlapCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) or [Physics2D.CircleCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html)?